# Does the BlackBerry Playbook Simulator support geolocation inside WebWorks application?

Tags: html, geolocation, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

I am testing HTML5 geolocation code inside a WebWorks application for BlackBerry Playbook, using the 0.9.4 Simulator in VMWare Player.  Here's the code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, options);
```

Launching the application gives a popup saying:

> Geolocation Request
>   local:// wants to access your location.

When I click "OK" this always results in a callback to the error handler function `geolocationError`, never the success handler.

The webpage works fine in Firefox 3.6.15 on Win 7.

Is there any way to test a successful geolocation request inside a WebWorks application in the Playbook simulator?

**Updates:**

- Geolocation works in the Playbook web Browser, so you can test your application as a web page in the Browser.
- I asked about this issue at a BlackBerry Developer Day and they confirmed this restriction.  I asked them to publish a list of known limitations, they said they would look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator as of 0.9.4 still has no support for geolocation, according to the [AIR SDK Release Notes](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21880/Known_issues_1524742_11.jsp).  It's likely the same limitations apply in this case.